# Cannot read property '1' of null error jqueryui

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I'm trying to use jquery dialog but I keep getting this error.

Div I use for the dialog:

```
<div id="save-dialog" title="Save">
    <p>Is this a tipo or a new patch? Leave blank if its a patch</p>
    <p>Enter patch like this:"CB 1"</p>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
    <input type="text" id="patch" value=""/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Complete JS:

```
    function savex(name){
    var desc = jQuery('input#'+name).val();
    var id = "<?php echo $_GET[id]; ?>";
    var patch = jQuery("#patch").val();
    jQuery("#save-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        height:300,
        width:300,
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
            "Saving": function(){

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'editcontentheroes.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: 'id='+id+'&desc='+desc+'&name='+name+'&patch='+patch,
                    always: function(output) 
                    {
                      history.go(0);
                    }
                });   
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

The function savex Is being called by a button. Tried to check for some empty variables but didnt found any problem with that.

Edit: the title its the error I get

Edit2: I'm using wordpress

Comment: What error? Is your title an error message?

Comment: Your error is missing.

Comment: the title is the error message

Comment: yes the title is the error message I get

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you are referencing 'this' within the function declared for 'Cancel', and attempting to access the 'dialog' element, however, 'this' in the scope of that function, actually references that function itself, and not the parent element, 'jQuery("#save-dialog")'.

You may want to change...

```
Cancel: function(){
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
```

to...

```
Cancel: function(){
            jQuery(this).parent.dialog("close");
        }
```

If this isn't the fix, then you will want to step through every debuggable line of the 'Saving' function.

Comment: @CristianoMarques Can you replicate your error in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/78rbp/

Comment: If this isn't the fix, then you will want to step through every debuggable line of the 'Saving' function.

Comment: I've found the problem is with WP :\ dunno how to fix it though. I was importing the jquery-ui but apparently its already there and I have to use that one.

Comment: What do you mean by "WP?"  WordPress?

Comment: Can you provide your 'Button' html?

Comment: <img src="http://strifehq.com/work/images/random/save.png" width="10" height="10" onClick="savex('attack');"/> but Im making a workaround because I think the problem is the jquery ui dialog isnt being correcly loaded by WP. I though about this: Making a div show in the middle to fill the rest of the information with a confirm JS as a button. then it would almost be the same.

Comment: This has the potential to be your issue.  You are passing 'attack' to the 'savex' function as the 'name' argument.  Then you use it to append to the JQuery selector string, 'input#'+name', but that input doesn't exist in the HTML you've provided. Thus, you will get an exception when attempting to access the 'desc' variable.